# Partial derivatives of $g(t) = f(x + ty)$ and $\phi (t) = \nabla f(x + ty)$ w.r.t. $t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I think I understand the simple case of chain rule where we want to differentiate scalar functions with scale domains. Now I am trying to apply this rule to compute the partial derivatives

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = y^T\nabla f(x + ty)$$
and
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial t}=  y^T\nabla^2 f(x + ty),$$

where $g(t) = f(x + ty)$ and $\phi (t) = \nabla f(x + ty)$
Could you please someone provide an educational (simple) proof on how we can compute the aforementioned partial derivatives and how the transpose appear?

Comment: Are you aware of the [chain rule for functions of several variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't use $\frac{d}{dx}f(g_1(x), \dots, g_k (x))=\sum_{i=1}^k  \left(\frac{d}{dx}{g_i}(x)\right) D_i f(g_1(x), \dots, g_k (x))$ before but it is fine by me if that is needed to proceed. I suppose $\frac{d}{dx}{g_i}(x)$ refers to $\nabla g_i (x)$ ?

Comment: No, the $g_i$ are scalar functions of one argument. In your case you will have $\frac{d}{dt}f(g_1(t),\dots,g_n(t))$, where $g_i(t) = x_i+ty_i$ are the components of the vector $x+ty$.

Comment: So no, it really means $\frac{d}{dt}$ and not $\nabla$. You will have $\frac{d}{dt}g_i(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(x_i+ty_i)=y_i$

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz thanks for the comments. In the definition it mentions that $D_i f$ is the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t it's i-th argument. As far as I understand, the arguments of $f$ are $g_i(t)$ so $D_i f = \partial f / partial g_i$? I found it strange. How do we write this more correctly?

Comment: $D_i f$ are already perfectly good notation, so you will have $D_i f(x+ty)$. If you really really want to use Leibniz notation, you have to give a name to $x+ty$, say $u=x+ty$, and write $$D_i f(x+ty) = \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u_i}\Bigg|_{u=x+ty}$$

Comment: Thank again. Does $\frac{d}{dx}f(g_1(x), \dots, g_k (x))=\sum_{i=1}^k  \left(\frac{d}{dx}{g_i}(x)\right) D_i f(g_1(x), \dots, g_k (x))$ hold also when $f$ is a vector? This is the case where you want to apply the rule for $\phi$.

Comment: Yes, in the case of $\phi$ you will have to apply that formula to each ot the components $\phi_i=D_if=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i}$.

Comment: Could you please provide the entire chain rule for this case? I can not see how the Hessian matrix is formed using your last comment..

Comment: It's the same as before, but for the components of the gradient. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, you have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x+ty)
&=
\sum_i D_if(x+ty)\frac{d}{dt}(x_i+ty_i) \\
&=
\sum_i D_if(x+ty)y_i \\
&=
\sum_i \phi_i(t)y_i \\
\end{align}
$$
since you defined
$\phi(t)=\nabla f(x+ty)$, in components this is
$\phi_i(t)=D_if(x+ty)$.
For the second part, apply $\frac{d}{dt}$ to this relation.
Using the same formula again, you will get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\phi_i(t)
&=
\frac{d}{dt}D_if(x+ty) \\
&=
\sum_j D_jD_if(x+ty)
\frac{d}{dt}(x_j+ty_j).
\end{align}
$$
can you write this in matrix form?
The Hessian will form because $D_j\phi_i=D_jD_if$.

Comment: Thanks. You mention that for the second part that we need to apply $\frac{d}{dt}$ in both sides. Sorry but I do not see the connection of  $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(x+ty)$  with $\frac{d}{dt}\phi (t)$. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: Also, $D_jD_i f$ are the elements of $\nabla^2 f$. How the Hessian $n \times n$ matrix is formed? I can not see that. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: About the first comment, you are right! at the beggining I had misunderstood what $\phi$ was. I edited the answer and hope it is clearer now. I apologize.

Comment: Ok thanks! For the matrix notation you just concatenate the $\frac{d}{dt}\phi_i(t)$ in the vector $\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t) = [\frac{d}{dt}\phi_1(t), \dots, \frac{d}{dt}\phi_n(t)]^T$ and use the last formula along with the structure of the Hessian. I think I got it now and I learned some new notation. Thanks.

Comment: @darkmoor I'm glad to have helped! Sorry for the notation confusion . If you think my answer is ok now, you can accept it to mark the topic as resolved. If there's something I can do to improve my answer, please let me know.